# The database session is not closed

Tags: sql, go, cockroachdb

When calling the `SetPersonStatusByName` function, a non-closing session occurs. Question: Did I miss anything to close the session after calling this function?

```
func (m *DBManager) SetPersonStatusByName(ctx context.Context, status int, name string) error {
    tx, err := m.db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("begin transaction: %w", err)
    }
    defer func(tx *sql.Tx) {
        rErr := tx.Rollback()
        if rErr != nil && !errors.Is(rErr, sql.ErrTxDone) {
            err = errors.Join(err, rErr)
        }
    }(tx)

    const selectForUpdate = `select status from persons where name=$1 for update;`
    if err = m.db.QueryRowContext(ctx, selectForUpdate, name).Err(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("select for update: %w", err)
    }

    const updateStatus = `update persons set status=$1 where name=$2;`
    if _, err = m.db.ExecContext(ctx, updateStatus, status, name); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("update row: %w", err)
    }

    err = tx.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("commit transaction: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: `database/sql.DB` pools the connections it opens, so it's expected for a connection to remain open after its first use (unless I misunderstand what you call "session" as there's no such thing in `database/sql`). You might want to read [this](http://go-database-sql.org/).

Comment: mkopriva means that when using a transaction, you're supposed to call methods such as `Exec*` on the variable containing the opened transaction, not on the DB. Think of it: what if you create 10 transactions and then perform `ExecContext` on the DB directly? What transaction that code is supposed to be executed "in"? What should happen if some queries/statements get executed concurrently by multiple goroutines?

Comment: @kostix Yes, thank you, I understood what I did in my code)

Comment: Could you share more details about "non-closing sessions occurs" are there any errors/logs you can share to clarify?
Also, as @kostix pointed out, if you are intending to do this in a transaction, you should be calling Exec on the `tx` variable.